# Jquery Ajax progress bar is not displayed properly in IE and FF

Tags: jquery

Iam using following jquery ajax code for Batch processing a PHP script with certain number of  records.  function  'do_ajax()' will do the batch processing.  everything is working fine in FF and progress bar is displaying progress of tasks(10%, 20%, 30%.....100%) that has been completed.

But in IE and Google Chrome, the progress bar is not loading the intermediate progress(10%, 20% etc). But it will loading final status(100%).

Also it will work in IE and Chrome, if I un-comment  following line

//alert(percentage);

Also tried with setTimeout, and  delay functions, but these are also returning same result

Below is the code used

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".big-link").click(function() {
        var rec_id = $(this).attr('id');
        var r=confirm("Do You really want to process?");
        if (r==true){                           
            $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({ value: 0});               
            do_ajax(start, offset);             
        }
    });
}); 

var total   = 50;   
var offset  = 10;
var start   = 0;


function do_ajax(){
    var cnt = 0;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        async:false,
        url: "createsubscrptn.php?start="+start+"&offset="+offset,
        error: function(xhr, status, error){
            alert(error);
            location.reload(true);
        },
        success : function (serverResponse){
            cnt = parseInt(serverResponse);
            percentage =    parseInt( (cnt/total)*100);
            //alert(percentage);
            $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({ value: percentage});
            start+=offset;                                                      
            if (start < total) {
                do_ajax();
            }
            alert('Process Completed');
            location.reload(true);
            exit();
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks in advance